# О формате результата запроса с плавающей точкой.

Tags: sql

У меня есть запрос

```
select (SELECT SUM(ostatok) FROM ostatky) AS ost
```

Результат запроса - число с плавающей точкой. Как сделать,  что бы результат отображался так: если есть дробная часть, тогда показывает число с двумя знаками после запятой, а если нет дробной части, тогда после запятой ставит два нуля. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

В MySQL есть функция округления `ROUND(n, m)`. n - число, m - кол-во знаков после запятой.

```
SELECT ROUND(10.555, 2)
```

Выведет `10.56`.

**UPD:** Еще есть функция [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format) она округляет дробную часть и форматирует число в `#,###,###.##`. После обработки с помощью FORMAT можно запятые заменить пробелами и на выходе округленное число с разрядами разделенными пробелами

```
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT(12345.678, 2), ',', ' ') # вывод 12 345.68
```

Comment: но, если будет не 10.555, а 10, то результат будет просто 10, а мне надо 10.00

Comment: Однотипные запросы возвращают набор колонок фиксированных типов не смотря на переменное условие. То есть, будет не `10`, а `10.0`. А в этом случае `ROUND` вернет `10.00`.

Comment: А SELECT ROUND(10, 2) выведет 10.00?

Comment: может еще подскажете как разбить результат запроса по три цифры, как в денежном формате... к примеру... 45 456,12

Comment: Нет, `SELECT ROUND(10, 2)` выведет просто `10`. А, вот, `SELECT ROUND(10.0, 2)` уже выведет `10.00`. То есть, если исходное выражение с плавающей запятой, то результат тоже - с плавающей запятой.

Дополнил ответ вариантом с использованием `FORMAT()`. Через нее можно и с разрядами решить проблему.

Но, в своим ответом я ответил на вопрос "как". А, в целом, я разделяю мнение @renegator. Форматирование вывода это уровень приложения а не базы данных.

Answer (score 1):

Отображение данных - работа приложения, которое данные использует. В нем и надо извращаться

Answer (score 0):

```
select (SELECT cast(SUM(ostatok) as dec(8,2)) FROM ostatky) AS ost
```

Comment: Зачем здесь вложенный select? o_O

Comment: Не нужен, но я оставил "орфографию и пунктуацию" автора, т.к. вопрос был в другом, и мне не хотелось проявлять занудство. :-)

Comment: кстати, все равно Ваш вариант не пашет(

Comment: Что именно?
Если размера не хватает, так увеличьте.